# Dictionary usage inside class, name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, global

So i was working on a school project but i cant seem to figure out why it says the name of "resultsByClassNameDic" is not defined

```
class Results ():

    ## Class that contains all kinds of things for handling grades (all classnames are in the dic below)

    # Variables
    resultsByClassNameDic = {"backend" : 0, "frontend" : 0, "database" : 0, "office" : 0, "english" : 0, "dutch" : 0, "calculus" : 0, "SLB" : 0, "L&B" : 0}

    # Functions
    def getGrade(className):

        ## Will return the grade for a certain class

        global resultsByClassNameDic

        grade = resultsByClassNameDic.get(className)

        return grade

def main ():

    ## Main Program 

    a = Results.getGrade("backend")
    print(a)


    return 0

### Main Program ###
if (__name__ == "__main__"):

    if (debugMode):

        doctest.testmod()

    main()
```

Comment: `Results.resultsByClassNameDic.get(className)`

Comment: Because it's a class attribute, not a global variable.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick